# Need to wait for asynchronous api callback before I return from method in Java

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, callback

```
  import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

  import quickfix.Initiator;


  public class UserSession {
    private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

public String await() {
        try {
            System.out.println("waiting...");
            if (latch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                System.out.println("released!");
            else
                System.out.println("timed out");
            return secret;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void countdown(String s) {
        System.out.println("In countdown: "+s+ ". Latch count: "+latch.getCount());
        secret = s;
        latch.countDown();
        System.out.println("Latch count: "+latch.getCount());
    }
  }


  public class LogonHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws IOException, ServletException
        {
            Map<String,String[]> query = request.getParameterMap();

            if (query.containsKey("method")) {
                if (query.get("method")[0].compareTo(method) == 0) {
                    baseRequest.setHandled(true);
                    response.getWriter().println(logon(query));
                }
            }
            else
                baseRequest.setHandled(false);
        }

    private String logon(Map<String,String[]> query) {
        if (query.containsKey("username") && query.containsKey("password") &&           query.containsKey("sendercompid")) {

            app.mapUser(query.get("sendercompid")[0], new   UserSession(query.get("username")[0], query.get("password")[0]));

            SessionID session = new SessionID(new BeginString("FIX.4.4"), new SenderCompID(query.get("sendercompid")[0]), new TargetCompID("PARFX"));

            try {
                ThreadedSocketInitiator tsi = new ThreadedSocketInitiator(app, app.getFileStoreFactory(), settings, app.getLogFactory(), app.getMessageFactory());
                UserSession userSession = new UserSession(query.get("username")[0], query.get("password")[0]);
                userSession.setInitiator(tsi);

                tsi.start();
                return userSession.await();
            } catch (ConfigError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
        }
        return "fail";
    }
  }


public class QuickfixjApplication implements Application {
    private Map<String,UserSession> users = new HashMap<String,UserSession>();

    public void mapUser(String s, UserSession u) {
        users.put(s, u);
    }

    public void toAdmin(Message message, SessionID sessionId) {

        try {
            if (message.getHeader().getField(new StringField(MsgType.FIELD)).valueEquals(Logon.MSGTYPE)) {
                UserSession user = users.get(sessionId.getSenderCompID());
                message.setField(new Username(user.getUsername()));
                message.setField(new Password(user.getPassword()));
            }
        } catch (FieldNotFound e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void fromAdmin(Message message, SessionID sessionId)
        throws FieldNotFound, IncorrectDataFormat, IncorrectTagValue, RejectLogon {

        if (message.getHeader().getField(new StringField(MsgType.FIELD)).valueEquals(Logon.MSGTYPE)) {
            System.out.println(message.toString());
            UserSession user = users.get(sessionId.getSenderCompID());
            user.countdown(message.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, I've tried to only include the minimum amount of code here. There are three interesting classes, UserSession is the internal glue between the Jetty handler and the QuickFix/j application.

The LogonHandler receives an HTTP logon request and tries to log a user onto a QuickFix/j application session.

QuickFix/j is sending a logon message to a FIX server, this logon request / response is asynchronous. The HTTP logon request is of course synchronous. So we have to wait for the reply from the FIX server before we return from the HTTP request. I do this using CountDownLatch and this UserSession object.

When I create the QuickFix/j session object I also create a UserSession object and add it to a map (that happens in the LogonHandler logon method).

There are two callbacks in the QuickFix/j application object, toAdmin() and fromAdmin(). In fromAdmin() I check if the message is a logon response and if it is I call a method of UserSession to countdown the latch. In debugging the code I see that the fromAdmin() method is hit, the UserSession object is found in the map and the countdown() method is called and the latch.getCount() goes from 1 to 0, but the latch.await() method in UserSession await() never returns. It always times out.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could use `CountDownLatch` like this:

```
public class LogonHandler implements Handler {
    private final CountDownLatch loginLatch = new CountDownLatch (1);

    private boolean callbackResults;

    public void serverResponseCallback(boolean result) {
        callbackResults = result;
        loginLatch.countDown ();
    }

    public boolean tryLogon(Credentials creds) throws InterruptedException {
        SomeServer server = new SomeServer(address);
        server.tryLogon (creds.getName (), creds.getPass ());
        loginLatch.await ();
        return callbackResults;
    }
}
```

If you want to limit waiting time by, for example, 5 seconds, then instead of `loginLatch.await ()` use the following:

```
if (loginLatch.await (5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    return callbackResults;
else
    return false; // Timeout exceeded
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, that's what I tried. The loginLatch.count() goes to 0 but the await() never releases.

Comment: @shaz `CountDownLatch` should work.  Probably error is in some other place of your code.  Could you post your code with `CountDownLatch` here?

Comment: @shaz Your code looks fine.  Once you said your latch goes to zero, while `await()` does not unblock, it is possible that you call `countdown` on one instance of `UserSession` object, while you call `await()` on another instance, i.e. on cloned instance?

Comment: So you mean the fact that I'm putting it in a HashMap?

Comment: waiting...java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@98350a[Count = 1]
Feb 18, 2013 11:45:14 AM quickfix.mina.SessionConnector startSessionTimer
INFO: SessionTimer started
Feb 18, 2013 11:45:14 AM quickfix.mina.initiator.InitiatorIoHandler sessionCreated
INFO: MINA session created for FIX.4.4:test9044->XXX: local=/172.16.34.167:60198, class org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketSessionImpl, remote=/172.17.22.52:8020
in onLogon method...
In countdown: FIX.4.4:test9044->XXX. Latch count: 1 java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@bb2bc3[Count = 1]
Latch count: 0
timed out

Comment: It does look like I'm dealing with different instances.

Comment: Thanks very much Mikhail, that was the error. I was adding a different instance of UserSession to my map.

Comment: `await()` function even blocking the callback response thereby freezing the app