# ExecutorService execute runnable in serial order

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I'm using executor service  with  newSingleThreadExecutor to execute my Runnable task in serial order, however seems to be serial execution order is not guaranteed, as sometime tasks are executed in random order.

```
executorService =  Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executorService.submit(MyTask1);
executorService.submit(MyTask2);
```

MyTask performs some Asynchronous operation and send the result back to the class from where I'm executing the task.

though docs says, with newSingleThreadExecutor () tasks has to be executed serially,Im not able to find out what I'm missing here.any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's likely that execution order is being lost in the asynchronous execution of your tasks. Why does `MyTask` have to run asynchronously when you're already using an executor service?

Comment: @ernest_k MyTask1 will connect to server and get some information from server on CallBacks, based on that information  i have to start the MyTask2.

Comment: based on your comment you should run task2 using some output of task1. In that case maybe its ok to return Future and add a condition checting task1 returned what you need before submitting task2?

Comment: How is the callback called? could it be that MyTask1 completes, then MyTask2, and finally the callbacks? what thread is executing the callback?

Comment: Your problem seems impossible to recreate as stated. Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to clarify.

Comment: By what means are you able to tell when any of the scheduled tasks have completed? Are you looking at some side-effect, such as timestamp on a file being created or a row inserted into database?

Comment: @Akceptor .. yeah.. Task1 will do some initial setup like creating an account and sessionId, that sessionId will be used by 2nd task Task2. so i have to guarantee that task will run that particular order only.

Comment: @mpb in this case you should wait for task1 to be completed before starting task2. But due to async nature of task1 you cant just submit task1 and task2 like you do. You have to return from tsk1 some result or set a flag and then check it in task2 before doing the actual job. In other words you have to wait until task1 is `completed`

Comment: @Akceptor in that  case i have change my Runnable to Callable  right?

Comment: yes and make sure you start task2 only after task1 is really completed. maybe something like mantioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929322/need-to-wait-for-asynchronous-api-callback-before-i-return-from-method-in-java

Answer (score 3):

Since execution order is guaranteed to be sequential, you are problably not using a single thread executor in the code you are *actually* running.

As a work around, submit *one* task that does *two* things:

```
executorService.submit(() -> {MyTask1.run(); MyTask2.run();});
```

Comment: ??? To quote [the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()): `Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially`

Comment: How does this solve the problem of async work being done (slowly) on the side?

Comment: @Bohemian .. How this is
     executorService.submit(() -> {MyTask1.run(); MyTask2.run();}); 

is different from

    executorService.submit((MyTask1));
    executorService.submit((MyTask2));

Comment: @mpb as the question is stated, it’s not different, but due to the symptom, I suspect the code being executed is not if fact as per the question but a different kind of executor is being used. This answer is a quick way to guarantee serial execution.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

If the results you are watching arrive out-of-order are being produced asynchronously, then all is well. Async work is being done on its own separate timeline. By definition, the async work launched by task # 1 may not complete until long after tasks # 1, 2, & 3 are all done (for example).

## Asynchronous means “don’t wait for me”

You mentioned:

> MyTask performs some Asynchronous operation

Asynchronous execution means the calling code need not wait for the async operation to complete.

The calling code, your task submitted to the executor service, makes the request for async work to be done, and the task immediately continues. If that task has no further work, the task is complete. So the executor service can move on.

The executor service moves on. The executor service executes the second submitted task. Meanwhile, the async work requested above may not yet be done. Perhaps the async work is waiting on a resource such waiting for a call over the network to return, or the async work is waiting for a database query to execute. That, by [definition of asynchronous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony_(computer_programming)), does *not* block the task submitted to the executor. The executor service is now running the 2nd submitted task, and may be a third or fourth, before, finally, your async work completes.

[image: diagram of a series of submitted tasks being executed sequentially along a timeline with separate async work being done in parallel along several tasks after being spawned from the first task]

## Feature, not a bug

In other words, a feature, not a bug. The [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) returned by [`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()) fulfilled its promise that “Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially”. The fact that as a by-product one of those tasks spins off async work does *not* change the fact that the tasks as submitted were indeed executed in their sequential order.

Comment: from logs i can make out , same thing is happening, once Task1 calls  the async operation, executor is moving on with Task2 without waiting for result of Task1.

Comment: @mpb Sounds right. If you wanted the executor to wait on Task1, you would make that workload synchronous rather than async.